# Unable to install package with WiX bootstrapper

Tags: c#, sql-server, wix, bootstrapping

I've a WiX Setup for my C# application.

I have a WiX Bootstrapper used to install application, .NET framework and SQL Server.

I have 2 problems with the installation for SQL server.

- On a PC with the application installed, my bootstrapper don't detect it and try to re install. On log file I see

> "Registry key not found. Key = 'HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL'"

But I checked with regedit, I got the register :

[image]

There is my code :

```
<util:RegistrySearch
    Id="SqlInstanceKeyFound"
    Root="HKLM"
    Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL"
    Value="SQLEXPRESS"
    Result="exists"
    Variable="SQLServerInstalled" />
```

- On a PC without the application, the installation failed with error 0x84b40000.

There is my code :

```
  <ExePackage Id="SQLExpressx64"
              SourceFile=".\Resources\SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"
              PerMachine="yes"
              Cache="no"
              Compressed="no"
              DownloadUrl="https://download.microsoft.com/download/0/4/B/04BE03CD-EAF3-4797-9D8D-2E08E316C998/SQLEXPR_x64_ENU.exe"
              Permanent="yes"
              Vital="yes"
              InstallCommand="/q /hideconsole /action=Install /features=SQL /instancename=SQLEXPRESS /enableranu=1 /sqlsvcaccount=&quot;NT Authority\Network Service&quot; /AddCurrentUserAsSqlAdmin /IAcceptSqlServerLicenseTerms /skiprules=RebootRequiredCheck"
              InstallCondition="VersionNT64 AND NOT SQLServerInstalled" />
```

Thank you for help

Comment: I made a test : run the setup and say "NO" to accord administrator rights. Then I opened log file. Error "Registry key not found." is present. Maybe I should check the register with admin rights ? How can I do ?

Comment: Win64="yes" in your registry search.

Comment: It works thank you ! Now I just have to achieve SQL Server install on PC without it

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert, however, I worked on this.

My code was (working):

```
<util:RegistrySearch 
   Id="regsearchSqlInstanceFound" 
   Root="HKLM" 
   Key="SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL" 
   Value="$(var.SqlInstanceName)" 
   Result="exists" 
   Variable="SqlInstanceFound"
/>
```

My value variable was :

```
<?define SqlInstanceName=MSSQLSERVER?>
```

Comment: I still have the error `[0D5C:3148][2016-11-08T15:21:04]i000: Registry key not found. Key = 'SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Microsoft SQL Server\Instance Names\SQL'`. However the register exists. I don't understand, this error will makes me crazy

Comment: My exePackage is (watch out, It was for 32 Bit) : `<PackageGroup Id="SqlServerPackageGroup">
      <ExePackage SourceFile="SQLEXPRWT_x86_FRA.exe" DetectCondition="SqlInstanceFound" InstallCommand="$(var.SqlInstallCommand)" UninstallCommand="$(var.SqlUninstallCommand)" RepairCommand="$(var.SqlRepairCommand)" />
    </PackageGroup>` I added a DetectCondition. You may need to add a detectionCondition with SQLServerInstalled?